# slow down verbose boot screen

Tags: linux, boot, logs

When Linux boots, with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` having `verbose` instead of `quiet`, the display on the console screen flies by so fast that it is near impossible to visually read what has a red [Failed] to it.

Is there a way to slow this down during boot?

I do not want to manually go into /var/log/boot.log.

it is this scrolling display that I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: send the boot messages to a serial port, if one is available ... you can also capture a video with your phone

Comment: If the system finishes booting even with the failure, you can use `dmesg`  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323188/how-to-get-kernel-boot-log-with-journalctl) also

Comment: 1. Record a video 2. View logs (dmesg, systemctl, journalctl). No, you cannot slow it down at least officially.